# Visual Studio not performing RVO when ternary operator is used and move/copy ctors are deleted

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

Looking at below code sample I would expect it to perform mandatory copy elision as part of Return Value Optimization (RVO) and compile with C++17 (/std:c++17) but it compiles with an error on Visual Studio 2017 (I'm using VS17, 15.9.8 more specifically).

```
class NoCopyOrMove
{
public:
    NoCopyOrMove() = default;
    NoCopyOrMove(int a, int b){}

    NoCopyOrMove(const NoCopyOrMove&) = delete;
    NoCopyOrMove& operator=(const NoCopyOrMove&) = delete;

    NoCopyOrMove(NoCopyOrMove&&) = delete;
    NoCopyOrMove& operator=(NoCopyOrMove&&) = delete;


private:
    int a, b;
};

NoCopyOrMove get(bool b) 
{
    return b ? NoCopyOrMove(1,2) : NoCopyOrMove();

    //if (b)
    //    return NoCopyOrMove(1, 2);

    //return NoCopyOrMove();
}

int main()
{
    NoCopyOrMove m = get(true);
}
```

Error is:

```
error C2280: 'NoCopyOrMove::NoCopyOrMove(NoCopyOrMove &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function
note: see declaration of 'NoCopyOrMove::NoCopyOrMove'
note: 'NoCopyOrMove::NoCopyOrMove(NoCopyOrMove &&)': function was explicitly deleted
```

NOTE: seems to compile on GCC and the the version with if/else compiles fine on both so not sure what I am missing.

I found a few other questions on stackoverflow, but they were from pre-c17 era and were mostly referring to "copy is called instead of move", hence asking again.

based on cppreference Copy elision happens:

> In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class
>   type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type:

and result of ternary operator should be a prvalue:

> a ? b : c, the ternary conditional expression for some b and c (see
>   definition for detail);

Any ideas why it doesn't compile?

---

Edit to use a simpler code:

given the NoCopyOrMove above, below code is also attempting to call move-ctor.

```
int main()
{
    volatile bool b = true;
    NoCopyOrMove m = b ? NoCopyOrMove(1,2) : NoCopyOrMove();
}
```

---

Update: [report link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/489863/c-copy-elision-not-performed-when-using-ternary-op.html)

Comment: "but it doesn't on visual studio." - if so, you could at least post what compilation error you get.

Comment: ops, sorry. edited the question

Comment: *Any ideas why it doesn't compile?* -- You should address this to Microsoft if you are certain this should compile.

Comment: Yes, it should compile in C++17. VS is known for lagging in implementing the latest C++ standard, however in the last years they have put a considerable effort on this.

Comment: @David: which version of MSVC and VS you are using?

Comment: okay, thanks everybody. I'll report on VS and update here when I get an update.

Comment: @P.W I'm using VS17, 15.9.8 more specifically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Is it a bug?

**Yes. This is a bug in MSVC.** Pretty much every other compiler that supports C++17 compiles it. Below we have the assembly produced by:

- ellcc https://godbolt.org/z/PfzDTs
- gcc https://godbolt.org/z/oXpDyk
- clang https://godbolt.org/z/KX99Yc
- power64 AT12.0 https://godbolt.org/z/XvWiEa
- icc 19.0.1 https://godbolt.org/z/pZWBJ5

And all of them compile it with `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++1z` (for ellcc).

## What does the standard say?

Conditional expressions (the ones formed by the ternary operator) produce values according to [these rules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) (see section 8.5.16).

Paragraph 1 of 8.5.16 describes sequencing, and parts 2 through 7 describe the value category of the resulting expression (see section 8.2.1 for a description of value categories).

- Paragraph 2 covers the case that either the second or third operands are void.
- Paragraph 3 covers the case that both the second and third operands are glvalued bitfields (i.e., not prvalues)
- Paragraph 4 covers the case the second and third operands have different types
- Paragraph 5 covers the case that the second and third operands are glvalues of the same type (also not prvalues)
- Paragraph 6:

> Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be applied to the operands (16.3.1.2, 16.6). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this subclause.

This gives us our answer. The result is a prvalue, so it's unnecessary to use the copy or move constructors, as the value will be instantiated in the memory provided by the calling function (this memory location is passed as a "hidden" parameter to your function).

### Does your program implicitly refer to the move constructor or the copy constructor?

Jon Harper was kind enough to point out that the standard states:

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed. (11.4.3.2)

This begs the question: does your program implicitly refer to the move constructor or the copy constructor?

**The answer to this is no.** Because the result of the conditional expression is a prvalue, no temporary is materialized, and as a result neither the move constructor or the copy constructor is referenced, either explicitly or implicitly. To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (emphasis mine):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. **The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible**, as the language rules ensure that no copy/move operation takes place, even conceptually:
>
> - In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type:
>
>   `T f() { return T(); }`
>
>   `f(); // only one call to default constructor of T`
> - In the initialization of a variable, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:
>
> `T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x`

## Distinguishing between NRVO and RVO

One source of contention is whether or not Copy Elision is guaranteed. It is important to distinguish between Named Return Value Optimization, and pure Return Value Optimization.

If you return a local variable, it's not guaranteed. This is Named Return Value Optimization. If your return statement is an expression that's a prvalue, it is guaranteed.

For example:

```
NoCopyOrMove foo() {
    NoCopyOrMove myVar{}; //Initialize
    return myVar; //Error: Move constructor deleted
}
```

I am returning a an expression (`myVar`) that is the name of an object of automatic storage. In this case, return value optimization is permitted but *not* guaranteed. Section 15.8.3 of the standard applies here.

On the other hand, if I write:

```
NoCopyOrMove foo() {
    return NoCopyOrMove(); // No error (C++17 and above)
}
```

Copy Elision *is* guaranteed, and no copy or move takes place. Similarly, if I write:

```
NoCopyOrMove foo(); //declare foo
NoCopyOrMove bar() {
    return foo(); //Returns what foo returns
}
```

Copy Elision *is still guaranteed* because the result of `foo()` is a prvalue.

## Conclusion

MSVC does, in fact, have a bug.

Comment: I clarified my answer and addressed section 15.8.3 of the standard, which only applies to named return value optimization.

Comment: Thanks a lot, accepted your answer!

I reported it, will post a link to that thread here tomorrow (once I get back to work)

Comment: MS has very poor C++17 elision support overall.

Comment: @David did the MSVC people ever reply?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez , It's "Under Investigation" here is the link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/489863/c-copy-elision-not-performed-when-using-ternary-op.html