# Should args to inherited constructors be copied when invoking the base ctor or not?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, inherited-constructors

For the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo()\n"; }
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "Foo(const Foo&)\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo()\n"; }
};

struct A
{
    A(Foo) {}
};

struct B : A
{
    using A::A;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    B b(f);
}
```

GCC gives:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
Foo()
Foo(const Foo&)
~Foo()
~Foo()
```

VS 2017 (also in C++17 mode) gives:

```
Foo()
Foo(const Foo&)
Foo(const Foo&)
~Foo()
~Foo()
~Foo()
```

Who's right, and why?

*(Let's also not forget that VS 2017 doesn't do mandated copy elision properly. So it could just be that the copy is "real" but GCC elides it per C++17 rules where VS doesn't...)*

Comment: This came up with more complicated machinery involving forward declarations and a smart-pointery argument type that doesn't quite require a complete type at point of declaration but obvs does on copy/destruction

Comment: Looks like a bug with MSVS to me.  Looks like they are still using the pre C++14 rules where the inherited constructor actually made a constructor in the derived class, instead of using it to initialize the particular base and defaulting everything else.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm convinced that's the case - don't have a VS2019 on me but I'd wager the feature is complete in that

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/55152552/560648

Comment: I do have 2019 and unfortunately, I get the same results as 2017 :(

Comment: @NathanOliver Hah ‍♂️

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that Visual Studio doesn't implement [P0136](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html) yet. The correct C++17 behavior is a single copy, the original C++14 behavior was two copies.

---

The C++14 rules ([N4140:[class.inhctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.inhctor)) would interpret:

```
struct B : A
{
    using A::A;
};
```

as:

```
struct B : A
{
    B(Foo f) : A(f) { }
};
```

The introduced constructors are speciifed in p3, the mem-initializer equivalence in p8. Hence you get two copies of `Foo`: one into `B`'s synthesized constructor and one into `A`'s real constructor.

---

The C++17 rules, as a result of P0136, are very different ([N4659:[class.inhtor.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.inhctor.init)): there, we directly invoke `A`'s constructor. It's not like we're adding a new constructor to `B` anymore - and it's not a mechanism that's otherwise expressible in the language. And because we're directly invoking `A(Foo)`, that's just the one single copy instead of two.

Comment: *the correct C++14 behavior was two copies*. Both GCC and Clang, make one copy of `Foo` even in C++14 mode: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oWveWPq3j

Comment: @Fedor They used to: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6xaYcYd9c. It's just that they no longer implement the defect behavior because, well, defects?

Comment: @Fedor, C++14 mode does not mean "all the bugs and defects present in the C++14 standard", because that would make no sense. When a defect in the standard is fixed, it's usually intended that the fix applies to older standard modes too. Please don't report GCC bugs for "this defect was fixed and `-std=c++14` doesn't give me the defect back". That's not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Elision notwithstanding, it looks to me like Visual Studio is wrong:

> [`[C++17: class.inhctor.init]/1:`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.inhctor.init#1) When a constructor for type `B` is invoked to initialize an object of a different type `D` (that is, when the constructor was inherited ([namespace.udecl])), **initialization proceeds as if a defaulted default constructor were used to initialize the `D` object and each base class subobject from which the constructor was inherited, except that the `B` subobject is initialized by the invocation of the inherited constructor**. The complete initialization is considered to be a single function call; in particular, the initialization of the inherited constructor's parameters is sequenced before the initialization of any part of the `D` object.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/ always links to the newest draft. If you want a specific C++ standard, follow the links from base website to find a historical version. The specific link for C++17: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.inhctor.init#1

Comment: @Justin Yeah tbh I just couldn't be bothered :P