# How to derive from vector class

Tags: c++, vector

Please help me understand how to create a derived class from `vector`. I understand deriving from standard containers is discouraged.

Here is my example:

```
// Example program
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Card
{
    int suit;
    int value;

    Card(int pSuit, int pValue) : suit(pSuit), value(pValue)
    {
    }
};

struct CardVector : public vector<Card>
{
    void removeCards(const CardVector &cardArr)
    {
        // todo
    }
};

int main()
{
    CardVector cardArr1;
    cardArr1.push_back(Card(1,1)); // works

    vector<Card> cardArr2{Card(1,1)}; // works
    CardVector cardArr3{Card(1,1)}; // doesn't compile

    return 0;
}
```

which gives the compile error

```
In function 'int main()':
30:32: error: no matching function for call to 'CardVector::CardVector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
30:32: note: candidates are:
16:8: note: CardVector::CardVector()
16:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided 
16:8: note: CardVector::CardVector(const CardVector&)
16:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Card' to 'const CardVector&'
16:8: note: CardVector::CardVector(CardVector&&)
16:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Card' to 'CardVector&&'
```

Comment: In general you shouldn't derive from standard container classes, but rather encapsulate them as member variables. Writing functions to allow iterating over `Cards` should be pretty easy to implement.

Comment: While that may be good advice, this is not the question "should I inherit from containers".

Comment: Compilation error question => [mcve] please

Comment: Very, very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: The first comment doesn't answer my question - saying an approach is "bad" is not a sufficient answer

Comment: @nathanesau That's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ruohola The question was briefly dupe-hammered to a question on that topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do it by `using` the base class constructor (and other methods too):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Card {
    std::string name;
};

class CardVector : public std::vector<Card> {

    using std::vector<Card>::vector;                    //   <- like so

    void removeCards(const CardVector& cardVector) {}
    void appendCards(const CardVector& cardVector) {}
};

int main() {
    Card a{"A"}, b{"B"};
    CardVector cv = {a, b};
    for(auto& c : cv) {
        std::cout << c.name << "\n";
    }
}
```

... but since the destructor of `std::vector` isn't virtual, be sure that you'll never delete objects though a base class pointer.

To avoid future headache, use composition and create proxy functions for those you need to support.

Lightness Races in Orbit shed some light on the compilation errors:
The cause was a missing ctor taking a `std::initializer_list` and to fix that you can either add one constructor (taking a `std::initializer_list<Card>` as an argument) or re-use the base class ctor as I did above. LRiO also shared *[VS to this day does an extra copy of ctor args when you inherit ctors like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56241478/560648)* which is certainly worth taking in consideration if you're using VS.

Comment: Would be extra good if you explain that the cause was a missing ctor taking initializer_list and that you can (A) add one, or (B) do as you've shown to re-use the base's ctors. Also be aware that [VS to this day does an extra copy of ctor args when you inherit ctors like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56241478/560648).

Comment: Thanks! I more or less copied what you wrote.