# Inheriting a class and re-using its constructors issue missing in the base class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using, overload-resolution

In the following program, `struct B` has two user-defined constructors: one from `int` and another from `int&&` (clearly this is not very practical). And an object of `B` is created from an l-value, which should unambiguously select the first constructor. Then `struct C` is derived from `B` inheriting its constructor by the `using`-declaration, and an object of `C` is created from the very same l-value:

```
struct B {
    B(int) {}
    B(int&&) {}
};

int i = 1;
B b(i); //ok everywhere

struct C : B {
    using B::B;
};

C c(i); //ok in Clang only
```

MSVC prints rather strange error in the last line:

```
source>(10): error C2668: 'B::B': ambiguous call to overloaded function
<source>(3): note: could be 'B::B(int &&)'
<source>(2): note: or       'B::B(int)'
<source>(10): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
```

despite l-value argument.

GCC error seems to agree and explains more:

```
source>:13:6: error: use of deleted function 'C::C(int) [inherited from B]'
   13 | C c(i);
      |      ^
<source>:10:14: note: 'C::C(int) [inherited from B]' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   10 |     using B::B;
      |              ^
<source>:10:14: error: call of overloaded 'B(int)' is ambiguous
```

At the same time Clang accepts the code just fine, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oGjzrYEhz

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Effectively the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240641/should-args-to-inherited-constructors-be-copied-when-invoking-the-base-ctor-or-n, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. There at least GCC and Clang behave the same unlike in this question.

Answer (score 0):

In C++14, GCC is right to reject `C c(i)`. According to [C++14: class.inhctor#8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.inhctor#8)

> An implicitly-defined inheriting constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written inline constructor for that class with a mem-initializer-list whose only mem-initializer has a mem-initializer-id that names the base class denoted in the nested-name-specifier of the using-declaration and an expression-list as specified below, and where the compound-statement in its function body is empty ([class.base.init]). If that user-written constructor would be ill-formed, the program is ill-formed. Each expression in the expression-list is of the form `static_cast<T&&>(p)`, where `p` is the name of the corresponding constructor parameter and `T` is the declared type of `p`.

the `struct C` definition is equivalent to

```
struct C : B {
    C(int p) : B(static_cast<int&&>(p)) {}
    C(int&& p) : B(static_cast<int&&>(p)) {}
};
```

where the call `B(static_cast<int&&>(p))` is indeed ambiguous.

And in C++17 standard the wording has changed [C++17: class.inhctor.init#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.inhctor.init#1), and Clang is right to accept the program according to new rules.